# Make menu entry visible depending on visibility of view in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to realize the following:

In my Eclipse plugin I have a menu entry (realized by adding a command to the plugin.xml and a handler class). Pressing the entry triggers some actions which depend on data shown in a view (also provided by the plugin).

Now, if the view is closed, the actions can't be done. I therefore think it would be good style to disable the menu entry when the view is not visible.

I've found [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html) which descibes how to disable/enable menues, but I have no idea how to combine it with the visibility of the view.

Can someone help out with that?

Edit: I've solved my problem in a different way. But greg's answer should usually solve this problem, as also stated in the official eclipse documentation:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```xml
<with variable="activePartId">
    <equals value="part id"/>
</with>
```

in the 'enabledWhen', 'activeWhen', or 'visibleWhen' expression (depending on exactly where you are using the expression).

For example to select when 'Project Explorer' is active:

```xml
<with variable="activePartId">
    <equals value="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer"/>
</with>
```

Comment: That sadly didn't work for me. Am I right that activePartId has to stay and I have to replace value="" with the id of the view I want the state of my menu entry to depend on? I understood it that way. enabledWhen and activeWhen caused the entry to be active, no matter what happened to the view I want to depend on, and using visibleWhen caused the entry _not_ to be shown no matter what.